# Directive to directive communication?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a page with two directives.
1. Directive that lists items , these items have a property on them call url
2. a directive on the same page that accepts url and displays it

What I want to do is, when the user clicks on one of the items in the first directive, to send that item.url to the 2nd directive as a parameter ?

What is the best practices for this scenario ?

Comment: Maybe [this](https://thinkster.io/a-better-way-to-learn-angularjs/directive-to-directive-communication) can help you.

Comment: Use scope variables in each and pass out and back in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few ways to achieve this:

**Common Parent Scope Property**

Specifically the parent controller encompassing both of your directives has a property for storing the selected URL. 
Then this property is passed into both of your child directives.

e.g.

```
<parent>
  <directive-one data-selected-url="selectedUrl"></directive-one>
  <directive-two data-url-to-display="selectedUrl"></directive-two>
</parent>
```

**Broadcast Events**

Have directive one broadcast an event on a scope that is shared by both directives.

e.g.

in directive one:

```
$scope.$broadcast('urlSelected', selectedUrl);
```

in directive two:

```
$scope.$on('urlSelected', function(event, selectedUrl) { ... });
```

NOTE: as I mentioned the scope needs to be a shared scope between the two directives, as broadcast sends the event DOWN the scope chain ($emit sends it up).

**Accessing Parent Controllers**

You could store the selected Url in a parent directive and have both children require that directive. They would then both be able to set/get the property from the parent directive.

e.g. in the child directives:

```
require: 'parentDirective'
link: function (scope, element, attrs, parentCtrl) {...}
```

Comment: P.S I would recommend the first approach. It is the simplest and most logical solution for your scenario.

Comment: Paul, you suggest the broadcast approach I presume ?

Comment: The first approach is more ideal I would say, i.e. the parent scope variable